# Select and extract row of data to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with big worksheet containing stocks information, with columns organized like this :

```
    ID     DATE       TIME     PRICE       QUANTITY    NBE
```

It goes on for 500k+ rows, and I have 10+ sheets to go through. I need to extract only the first two trade of each trading day, and create a new list on a new sheet (Sheet1). The first trade of every day is always at "09:00:00".

So far I wrote this piece of code, in which I tried to copy the two lines I need and then paste them into Sheet1 thus creating the new list. It runs without errors, but nothing shows up...

```
Sub Macro1()

i = 2
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

For Each Cell In Selection
 If Day(.Range("B" & cRow).Value) <> Day(.Range("B" & cRow - 1).Value) Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 1).Paste
    i = i + 2
End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Shouldn't i select and the copy paste the two rows together? Or is it possible to create a range consisting of 2 rows and 6 columns from the activecell and then copy paste that range?

EDIT 1: It's not working.. I updated it like above, but I still get an error 438 here ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Paste

EDIT 2: I'm def a big noob. Just realized not every first trade was made at 9:00:00 so i need to select the row based on wether or not one day have passed, and select the first two. 
Can I use this condition instead : If Day(Range("B" & cRow).Value) <> Day(Range("B" & cRow - 1).Value) Then ?

Comment: I suspect using `Cell` instead of `ActiveCell` inside your loop would be of some help. That said, while I am not entirely sure whether or not `Cell` is a reserved term in VBA, I think I would have named my variables something less likely to already have a use.

Comment: stop selecting things!

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Set the range to search using something like `Dim range_to_search As Range: Set range_to_search = Range(ActiveWorksheet.Range("C2"), ActiveWorksheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)` instead. Honestly I'd prefer it if you referenced the worksheet to search explicitly (like you do with Sheet 1 further down the macro) instead of using `ActiveWorksheet` too, but that's not quite as egregious.

Comment: i suggest my code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  should do it quickly

make sure your on the sheet with data and run it, and it will copy it onto sheet1 in the same workbook starting at row2

you should make sure sheet1 is empty also , with .clearContents

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim lngFirstRow As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim cRow As Long
    Dim shSrc As Worksheet

    Dim lngNextDestRow As Long
    Dim shDest As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shSrc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set shDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With shSrc

        lngFirstRow = 2
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        lngNextDestRow = 2

        For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow Step 1

            If Format(.Range("C" & cRow).value, "hh:mm:ss") = "09:00:00" Then

                .Rows(cRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow )

                   .Rows(cRow+1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow+1 )

                lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 2

            End If
        Next cRow

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Ye I tried it before the update and i got a bug with the function and the lastusedrow object..
Anyway thanks a lot, it works. I need to look into it deeper cause i must be able to explain the code in details!

Comment: And you're right, I should get the habit of naming things, instead of selecting them! 
I am still a very big noob lol 
Thanks again man

Comment: keep in mind this will paste at row 2 everytime on sheet1,  you would need to tell it to look for the last row, just like i have for looking at the last row on  the active sheet if you want to keep building up data

Comment: Yes I will! 
I am going to adapt it and run it thought my collection of sheets, and build my new database. I'll repost here if i get into trouble.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to check if one day have passed? I realized the condition of the time of the trade wasn't good enough, and it was poorly chosen from my part...
I tried with If Day(.Range("B" & cRow).Value) <> Day(.Range("B" & cRow - 1).Value) Then

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting that your `Time` column is formatted as a Date/Time field, so you're comparing a string `09:00:00` to a long (date/time) and it's never going to be equal.

Try this:

```
if Format(Cell.Value, "hh:mm:ss") = "09:00:00" Then
```

And your English isn't bad at all...

Comment: thanks man, didn't pay attention to that detail! 
And, yeah might not be bad, but i'm still under the impression of making constant mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

When you refrence a sheet using the following line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Rows(i).Paste
```

`Sheet1` is likely a variable that is not defined properly. If "Sheet1" is the actual name of the sheet then enclose it in doublequotes

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Paste
```

After looking at @FreeMan's answer....you should do that first. You'll probably get an error 9 subscript error after you fix what he said to do.